# Access: Criteria in A Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, criteria

I'm trying to make an update query, I've added `Holiday ID`,`Holiday Name`, and `Cost` to the query and am trying to find a way to set the criteria for Holiday Name to select Thanksgiving, Christmas, and New Years. I thought it would be simply

`[Holiday Name]="Thanksgiving" "Christmas" "New Years"`

but that didn't turn out very well. Any and all help is much appreciated.

Comment: the holiday name isn't all three is it?   it's not Thanksgiving Christmas Newyears... it's one of the three IN that list right? or put another way it's `[holiday name] of 'Thanksgiving' or [holiday name] of 'Christmas' or [holiday name] of 'new years'`  In access I think separate lines in the OR section of query builder.

Comment: FYI: http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/ I found this very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
WHERE [Holiday Name] in ('Thanksgiving', 'Christmas', 'New Years');
```